# AWS : S3FS AMI and load balancer high I/O Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-ami, s3fs

I am trying to setup the project environment over AWS .. As per my little bit of research I came to know about S3 buckets service. And I also come to know that If I will put our code files inside that S3 bucket will be much more relevant then putting those same inside NFS or other file sharing systems.

Right now I am having one EC2 instance over AWS, and inside that same I have tried to setup **S3FS** and via some settings I have got all my bucket's files and folder inside our EC2 environment. And I am so impressed with that same too. But our project is running with heavy load of CPU and memory. So without setting up load balancer that same project (with same S3FS configured image AMI). That will be worthless for me.

Now I already created the AMI image for that same S3FS configured EC2 instance, and when my scale-up load balancer policy tried to create one spot request for that image(AMI) .. I seen high I/O rates !!! Due to that unexpectedly project running very slow !!

**Can any one suggest me better way how can I reduce high I/O rates on new launched S3FS enabled instances ??**

Comment: S3FS volumes should not be used as a block device. Under the covers all it does is copy the files to a temp directory and sends the files back and forth as you access or modify them. You can copy your application from S3, but do not run it on it

Comment: Hello datasage,

Thanks for your reply. And I agreed with your comment. Here one thing comes to my mind .. Please let me know If that will going to causes any issue (hence I am not that much familiar with networking fundas)

1) I will mount one folder (say folder1) for project with the help of S3 mount software

2) Then I will prepare another folder (separate then S3 mounted one) (say folder2).. Which will going to sync S3 mounted folder. And folder2 will my project access URL.

3) I will going to sync mounted folder to another folder periodically (such like 1 hour of interval)

Comment: Well it might work, although I've had problems with tools like rsync on an s3fs mounted volume. You can also use the sync option of `s3cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to take a look at the new project RioFS (Userspace S3 filesystem): https://github.com/skoobe/riofs. This project is “s3fs” alternative, the main advantages comparing to “s3fs” are: simplicity, the speed of operations and bugs-free code. Currently the project is in the “testing” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time.

We are seeking for more people to join our project and help with the testing. From our side we offer quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

Regarding your issue:

I'm not quite sure how does S3FS works with cached files, but in our project we try to avoid performing additional I/O operation.

Please give it a try and let me know how [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) works for you !

Comment: Hello Wizzard,

Let me check RioFS .. I will let you know If I will find any issue with it.